# Weapon rotation with added arm offset

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I set up IK on my player's arms so that they properly grasp my gun regardless of the rotation of it. However, my gun only rotates in place, which makes it unrealistic and doesn't look good. Is there any way to make the gun rotate about a point? (AKA it's parent, the player)

Here's my current code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField]
    Transform Player, Weapon;

    float yRotation = 0.0f;
    float mouseSensitivity = 100f;

    float armOffset = 0.5f;

    void Update() {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Rotate();
    }

    private void Rotate () {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

        yRotation -= mouseY;

        Mathf.Clamp(yRotation, -80, 85);

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(yRotation, 0f, 0f);
        Player.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
    }
}
```

I tried to fix it using a script I had used to add offsets to my 2d game, but this didn't work:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField]
    Transform Player, Weapon;

    float yRotation = 0.0f;
    float mouseSensitivity = 100f;

    float armOffset = 0.5f;

    void Update() {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Rotate();
    }

    private void Rotate () {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

        yRotation -= mouseY;

        Mathf.Clamp(yRotation, -80, 85);

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(yRotation, 0f, 0f);
        
        Vector3 playerToMouseDir = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - Player.position;
        transform.position = Player.position + (armOffset * playerToMouseDir.normalized);

        Player.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you basically have it Done.

Just attach the weapon as a child of the player, and then apply your rotation to ONLY the player and not the weapon. That should allow your weapon to move relative to the player.